# Diff arrays containing JSON with Node.js

Tags: json, node.js, diff

I have two arrays `old`and `new`with this kind of structure stored as `.json` files:

```
[
    {
        "hardware": {
            "screen": "big",
            "name": "iPhone 6 Plus"
            "colors available": ["spacegrey", "gold"]
        },
        "software": {
            "OS": "iOS",
            apps: ["Apple Music", "Contact"]
        }
    },
    {
        // hardware and software JSON arrays again, more than 30000 phones in the file
    }
]
```

I want to diff these two `.json` files, I tried with a lot of packages ([archiver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/archiver), [jsdiff](https://www.npmjs.com/package/archiver), [jsondiffpatch](http://jsondiffpatch)) but I haven't find something able to give me the lists of phones removed or added. I don't care if a phone has been modified, it should be considered as a phone removed and another phone added.

Is there a package to do this kind of diff or should I write the algorithm by myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case [objectDiff.js](https://github.com/NV/objectDiff.js) works pretty well too.
Here is a live [**demo**](http://nv.github.io/objectDiff.js/) mapping differences on two objects

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a package to do specifically what you are trying to achieve. Try this:

```
// Returns a list of phones added or removed
function phonesAddedOrRemoved(listA, listB) {
    return [].concat(phonesAdded(listA, listB), phonesRemoved(listA, listB));
}
// Returns of a list of phones removed
function phonesRemoved(listA, listB) {
    return phonesDiff(listA, listB);
}
// Returns a list of phones added
function phonesAdded(listA, listB) {
    return phonesDiff(listB, listA);
}

// Returns phones in listA but not in listB
function phonesDiff(listA, listB) {
    return listA.filter(function (phone) {
        return listB.filter(function (_phone) {
            return phone.hardware.name === _phone.hardware.name;
        }).length === 0;
    });
}
```

Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/8uz6fy8q/